# element style in browsers make images displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found that the image in my site beeing display: none !important without any styling .. so I inspect the page I found that (element.style) default of browser make display none

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks but i tried to make it easy

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it was from ADBLOCKER because the image folder was named (ads) so adblocker block it

Comment: yup, that make sense, had same issue in the past with images prefixed "ad-"..